# WP site struggling to refresh

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, cache, refresh

I used to think this was an issue with Google Chrome, when I would struggle to get pages to refresh with their latest CSS styles — despite me having the option set to disable cache when inspector tools are open.

More recently however, I've noticed I get this problem with php files too, e.g. WordPress templates files. I will often make changes to them, upload via FTP and have to refresh my browser multiple times in order to see the changes.

Tonight things seem unusually bad. I've even tried renaming the folder for the theme that I am building, which *should* break everything... but my whole website is loading as normal as though nothing has changed. It is so bad at refreshing that I can't even break it!

I have a template file called `contact.php` which I can't get to refresh to the latest version... I've also tried renaming the file in order to break it, but WP is *still* loading the page with that template.

I've even tried `get_page_template()` which confirms that it is the `contact.php` that is applied to the page despite me having renamed it on the server

Could this be an issue with my hosting company? or should I look at caching plugins?

Comment: Did you try disabling and clearing cache plugins?

Comment: I don't have any cache plugins installed, might it be worth trying one?

Comment: Don't add a cache plugin while this problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you are not running a cache in Wordpress) The problem here could exist in 3 or 4 places -

1. In your browser.
2. In the setup for your webserver or website.
3. With an ISP between you.   (This is highly unlikely, and if you are using HTTPS and are not in a corporate environment where they control your device this is not the case).
4. If you are using a caching/cdn service this could be a source of caching as well.

What is likely happening is that (1) and (2) are working in concert - specifically when a page is requested the webserver is adding "Cache-Control" headers, which your browser then remembers.    This can be done in Wordpress, or in a .htaccess file or in the web server configuration, or, if you are using something like Cloudflare at their side.   **To ascertain this is happening you can try flushing your browser cache or using an alternative browser.  Alternatively only in some cases you can simply throw ?random-content at the end of the url, or open a private browsing Window**

If that works, then you know the problem is outside your Wordpress setup and you should look at any .htaccess or web server configuration file you have, or raise it with your ISP.

Comment: Using `?random-content` parameters will help get a fresh initial page load, but probably won't have any effect on cached CSS, JS, and images that the page is using.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Yup.  I'll update the post for completeness.  Absolutely right on the ?random-content bit (hence the only in some cases I added)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried reloading the page in Incognito mode and also tried adding a `?` variable in the URL but still no luck

Comment: ...I've even tried clearing my browser cache + all history but that still doesn't work! might it be worth me contacting my hosting company? probably a last resort as they take forever to reply

Comment: I've just tried contacting my hosting company but they said it's beyond their scope of support

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the correct location. (For example, I have multiple servers. Occasionally I do something stupid like edit an old copy rather then a current one. Everything changes but nothing works).

Comment: I've just realised now that I'd accidentally moved the template file into the CSS folder and that WordPress was using that! OH MY GOD

Comment: ...thanks for all the help everybody 